# Duplicate symbols for facebbok library i386 architecture

Tags: facebook, cordova

I try updating Phonegap application to 2.9 with updating facebook sdk to recent version.
I've completed update guide and re-attached Facebook SDK. Could find an answer that would help in other stackoverflow issues.

I'm getting error

```
ld: 41 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
```

What I have tried so far:

1. Removed Facebook SDK from Buid Phases: this leads to facebook classes not found. Reverted.
2. Verified plugin is in 'ios' subgroup
3. Verified frameworks are attached

Config screenshots: [1](http://screenshots.ryotsuke.ru/scr_a9a457dd8f3b.png) [2](http://screenshots.ryotsuke.ru/scr_faf30f6bf87e.png) [3](http://screenshots.ryotsuke.ru/scr_517b77631a2e.png)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Facebook iOS sdk are you using? If it is 3.5, try downgrading to 3.2 and see if that works. Phonegap Facebook plugin is a bit outdated and seems to have issues with the latest ios sdk.